# How is Gradle handling the resources folder by default?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jvm, windows-11

I've got a Compose Desktop application with the following structure:

```
project
    /src
        /main
            /kotlin
                *.kt files; lot's of them
            /resources
                /sql
                    query1.sql
                    query2.sql
```

Inside the project I use a *random* config to read the resources with:

```
val query = MainConfig::class.java.getResource("/sql/create_schema.sql").readText()
```

This works fine on the development system and the application is able to read the queries. However, when I run whatever Gradle task like `createReleaseDistributable` or `packageDistributionForCurrentOS` and either copy it to the target system or install, the app crashes becase the queries are missing.

My `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.22"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.5.12"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    google()
}

dependencies {
    // ...
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        javaHome = System.getenv("JDK_17")
        jvmArgs += listOf("-Xmx2G")
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Exe)

            packageName = "project"
            packageVersion = "1.0.1"
            includeAllModules = true
            windows {
                perUserInstall = true
            }
        }

        buildTypes.release.proguard {
            isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

tasks.wrapper {
    // https://gradle.org/releases/
    gradleVersion = "8.6"
    // You can either download the binary-only version of Gradle (BIN) or
    // the full version (with sources and documentation) of Gradle (ALL)
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}



kotlin {
    target {
        compilations.all {
            compilerOptions.configure {
                jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_17)
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Is it necessary to add something to it so that the application can work with the resources when deployed? It obviously knows what to do when run via IntelliJ, but not when it's deployed. Why is that so?

Also, am I supposed to find these files in some folder or are they compiled into another file like a `*.jar` or something java specific? If so, which `*.jar` should contain them?

What I also did, is to print the default resource paths with:

```
sourceSets {
    main{
        resources {
            srcDirs.forEach {
                println(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly shows the location of the `resources` folder and yet the release version doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable! The runtime accesses resources directly from the disk during development in a case-insensitive way, but requires the exact case when accessing them later from the `*.jar`!

Of course it doesn't warn you about that. It just crashes and the [`getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) documentation doesn't even mention case sensitivity.

The answer the main question is: gradle handles the [`resources`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_resources) automatically.